# Сигнатура конструктора в интерфейсе

Tags: java

Почему нельзя в интерфейсе задать сигнатуру конструктора без реализации?

Comment: потому что конструктор не является частью интерфейса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерфейсы не должны описывать объекты и их поля, они должны описывать действия. Поэтому в интерфейсе нельзя описать сигнатуру конструктора.

Comment: однако внутренний класс и реализацию метода в нем мы в интрфейсе описать можем

Answer (score -1):

интерфейс не может "знать" к какому классу он будет применен, отсюда нет возможности знать о конкретном методе - конструкторе класса